# Numpy Crop 2D Array to Non-NaN Values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D Numpy array which contains an island of data surrounded by an ocean of NaNs.

I would like to crop the array such that it contains only the bounding box and the contents of the non-NaN region.

I would also like to know the indices and size of this box with respect to the original array.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.empty((15,10))
a.fill(np.nan)
a[7,6] = 76
a[8,5] = 85
a[9,5] = 95
a[9,7] = 97
```

Now we have an array with 15 rows and 10 columns, containing an island of data in a sea of NAN:

```
nan,  76.,  nan,
85.,  nan,  nan,
95.,  nan,  97.,
```

Next:

```
nans = np.isnan(a)
nancols = np.all(nans, axis=0) # 10 booleans, True where col is all NAN
nanrows = np.all(nans, axis=1) # 15 booleans

firstcol = nancols.argmin() # 5, the first index where not NAN
firstrow = nanrows.argmin() # 7

lastcol = len(nancols) - nancols[::-1].argmin() # 8, last index where not NAN
lastrow = len(nanrows) - nanrows[::-1].argmin() # 10
```

And finally:

```
a[firstrow:lastrow,firstcol:lastcol]
```

Shows us the island:

```
array([[ nan,  76.,  nan],
       [ 85.,  nan,  nan],
       [ 95.,  nan,  97.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and used @John Zwinck's answer as inspiration. I provide an alternate solution that removes all the NaNs from the array. It assumes that the non-NaN data is "whole", in that it is surrounded by NaNs, but does not contain NaNs within it. Such as this data set here:

```
import numpy as np
image = np.empty((15,10))
image.fill(np.nan)
image[1,5] = 1
image[2,3:6] = 1
image[3,3:7] = 1
image[4,3:8] = 1
image[5,2:9] = 1
image[6,1:9] = 1
image[7,1:8] = 1
image[8,1:8] = 1
image[9,1:9] = 1
image[10,2:7] = 1
image[11,2:] = 1
image[12,4:6] = 1

print(image)
[[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan nan nan  1. nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan  1.  1.  1. nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan  1.  1.  1.  1. nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. nan nan]
[nan nan  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. nan]
[nan  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. nan]
[nan  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. nan nan]
[nan  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. nan nan]
[nan  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. nan]
[nan nan  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. nan nan nan]
[nan nan  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan nan  1.  1. nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]]
```

Firstly, crop off all the columns and rows that contain all NaNs, recording index values for the top left corner of the new array relative to the old array.

```
nans = np.isnan(image) #Find position al all the NaNs
nancols = np.all(nans, axis=0) # Find all the columns that have only NaNs
nanrows = np.all(nans, axis=1) # Find all the columns that have only NaNs
top_left_x = nancols.argmin() # position of the left most column that does not contain all NaNs
top_left_y = nanrows.argmin() # position of the top most column that does not contain all NaNs
cropped_image = image[:,~nancols][~nanrows] #remove all the rows and columns that are all NaNs
print(cropped_image)
[[nan nan nan nan  1. nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan  1.  1.  1. nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan  1.  1.  1.  1. nan nan nan]
[nan nan  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. nan nan]
[nan  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. nan]
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. nan]
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. nan nan]
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. nan nan]
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. nan]
[nan  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. nan nan nan]
[nan  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
[nan nan nan  1.  1. nan nan nan nan]]
```

Next, iterate over the image by removing the row or column with the most NaNs, until the image is NaN free.

```
while np.any(np.isnan(cropped_image)): #Loop over the image until there a no NaNs left
    nans = np.isnan(cropped_image) # Locate all NaNs
    nans_in_cols = np.sum(nans,axis=0) # Figure out how many NaNs are in each column
    nans_in_rows = np.sum(nans,axis=1) # Figure out how many NaNs are in each row
    if np.max(nans_in_cols) > np.max(nans_in_rows): # Remove the column or Row with the most NaNs, if it first row or column of the image, add 1 to the top left x or y coordinate
        cropped_image = np.delete(cropped_image, np.argmax(nans_in_cols), 1)
        if np.argmax(nans_in_cols) == 0: top_left_x += 1
    else:
        cropped_image = np.delete(cropped_image, np.argmax(nans_in_rows), 0)
        if np.argmax(nans_in_rows) == 0: top_left_y += 1
print(cropped_image, top_left_x,top_left_y)
[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. 1.]] 3 3
```

This is the new array, where the top left corner corresponds to position [3,3] in the original array.